# Hibernate Strange "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into" Error

Tags: hibernate, ora-01400

there is a strange error ocurring to me. I'm working with Hibernate, I have mapped class called Widget, which has a Parameter class, but when I try to insert I get
"ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into..."

The mapping is properly done as:

```
<bag cascade="none" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="parameters" table="PARAMS" >
  <key column="WIDGET_ID" foreign-key="FK_PARAMS" not-null="true"/>
  <one-to-many class="Parameter"/>
</bag>
```

The wierd thing is that the not-null property is setted to "true" which forces to insert the ID value of the Widget Object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the mapping is <bag cascade="none" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="parameters" table="PAGE_WIDGET_PARAMS" >
      <key column="PAGE_WIDGET_ID" foreign-key="FK_PAGE_WIDGET_PARAMS_1" not-null="true"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.esolutions.claro.orga.pages.widgets.WidgetParameter"/>
    </bag>

Answer (score 0):

Did you solved the problem? I think I had the same problem

[ORA-01400: Cannot insert null into (TABLE.COLUMN) (Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889728/ora-01400-cannot-insert-null-into-table-column-hibernate/36933528#36933528)

In my case I solved modifying Db, making foreign keys also primary keys